# Пытаюсь подружиться с Web SQL Database

Tags: база-данных, webbrowser, websqldatabase

В хром всё норм, в Firefox

> openDatabase is not defined

Нагуглил вот такую статью 
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/comparing-indexeddb-and-webdatabase/

Насколько я понял FF не хочет поддерживать Sql?

Код выдающий ошибку на FF

```
try {
    var db = openDatabase('chatDb', '1.0', 'Db client', 5 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function (t) {
        t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id UNIQUE, log)');
        //t.executeSql("DROP TABLE CHAT");
        t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CHAT ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, 'name', 'message','groupe_all' TINYINT(1))");
    });


    db.transaction(function (t) {
        t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM CHAT", [], function (t, result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                console.log(result.rows.item(i));
            }
        }, null);

    });
} catch (exp) {
    //console.log(exp);
}
```

Comment: Я что-то не увидел где в статье пишется о том, что FF не хочет поддерживать `sql`? Все там работает, только обзывается индексд ДБ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда почему ошибка? про то что не хочет читал на других ресурсах

Comment: Покажите код, который выполняете. А вообще, может щас угадаю. Вы пытаетесь работать с `indexedDB`, как с `webSQL`, теми же методами, или вообще думаете, что это одно и то же. А это совсем разные базы. В хроме, новой опере (которая на вебките), сафари  надо работать  с `webSQL`, а в фарйфоксе используется `indexedDB`, в которой немного отличаются методы работы

Comment: Сделаю наверное проще пусть FF запрашивает архив сообщений у Хрома =) будет чуть тупее работать в FF ну да и ладно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openDatabase is not defined` высвечивается потому, что `Firefox` решил не реализовывать хранилище `webSQL`. Соответственно и методы, функции и прочее, что работает с `webSQL` - выдает ошибку в `FF`.

Для работы с локальным хранилищем `FF` предлагает альтернативу `IndexedDB`. И соответствующие методы для работы с ним. Как работать с ним можно посмотреть [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB) или в ссылке, что вы написали. Там же четко описано, что есть разница и приводятся примеры различия обращения к базе, её создание и прочее.

В общем целом, для работы с локальным хранилищем, если хотите чтобы работало и в хроме и в лисе и пр, по-хорошему, надо сделать, к примеру, два файла:
`webSQL.js`  и `IndexedDB.js` в которых отдельно будет описана логика работы с той или иной базой.

При инициализации страницы, где предполагается работать с хранилищем сделать проверку на браузер. В зависимости от браузера подключать тот или иной скрипт.

Браузеры, поддерживающие тот или иной вид локального хранилища можно посмотреть здесь:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage

и здесь:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb